# operation not permitted Error response from daemon: Cannot start container System error: operation not permitted

Tags: docker, raspberry-pi2, archlinux-arm

I have installed ArchLinux on docker in raspberryPi 2 and loaded basic image hello-world.
I am getting this error:

> [root@alarmpi ~]# docker run hello-world 
>   *operation not permitted Error response from daemon: Cannot start container System error: operation not permitted*

But I want to run mongo db image on docker of arch linux.

Comment: I would like to know the answer to this as well. Usually, raspberry pi only accepts arm based images but even trying to run images from `docker search armhf-` gives me the error mentioned above.